# How to create a method in WCF RESTful service in the given scenario?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I have to create a PUT RESTful WCF service which will have URI template something like this:

```
/rs/close_copy/{user_token}?term={term}&brand={brandname}
```

The request that comes to us has a JSON body in this format:

```
“acc”: 
“counters”:[ 
{“format”: 
“ink”: 
“ctr”:
“duplex”: },
{…}]
```

But the issue is, `"counters"` parameter of above doesn't always come as an array of JSON Object as expected. When there is only one element in `"counter"`, the request comes as a single JSON object and not as a list of JSON object with one element.

It's the third party who is calling our service and they can't make the changes to their request. I have implemented in WCF something as below:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate = "/rs/close_copy/{user_token}?term={term}&brand={brandname}")]
JsonResponse EndSession(string user_token, string term, string brandname, EndSessionRequest request);
```

where `EndSessionRequest` is :

```
[DataContract]
public class EndSessionRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string acc { get; set; }        

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<PageDetails> counters { get; set; }
}
```

and `PageDetails` is:

```
[DataContract]
public class PageDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string format { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ink { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ctr { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool duplex { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with above implementation is, when the `counters` has one element, request comes to us like:

```
{"acc":"ramaccnz","counters":{"ctr":"2","duplex":"false","format":"A4","ink":"bw"}}
```

But as per our implementation, request is expected as:

```
{"acc":"ramaccnz","counters":[{"ctr":"2","duplex":"false","format":"A4","ink":"bw"}]}
```

In other cases, when request has multiple elements, our service work as expected.

Is there a way to handle this in WCF implementation?

Comment: Your code is right, the problem is the third party client that is not calling your service rightly, respecting your service contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by getting the request string in JSON format using `OperationContext`, and then handling the request manually by using `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Below is my code snippet:

```
[DataContract]
public class EndSessionRequestMany
{
    [DataMember]
    public string acc { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<PageDetails> counters { get; set; }
}

public JsonResponse EndSession(string user_token, string term, string brandname)
{
    string JSONstring = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(JSONstring));
    EndSessionRequestMany objEndSessionMany = (EndSessionRequestMany)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EndSessionRequestMany)).ReadObject(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright. That's kinda tricky. I'm working on a RESTful Service as well at the moment. There's something called [CollectionDataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) maybe thats one way to achieve your aim, but I'm new to WCF so I can't tell you more.
Another way would be to get the raw data stream you're request comes with, so you'll have to fetch and deserialize the JSON Data yourself by using the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this case you could handle the incomming data yourself. Like..

```
 public JsonResponse ServiceCall(Stream dataStream, object parameter) {
     var dataBytes = dataStream.ReadToEnd();
     // use the required encoding to get the string data
     var dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBytes);
     var dataJson = default(EndSessionRequest);
     try { dataJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<EndSessionRequest>(); }
     catch {  
         // the request includes just one entry that's why
         // the serializer fails getting the object so
         // you could continue like..
         dataJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<EndSessionRequestWithSingleCounter>();
     }
     // handle request ...
 }
```

To use the raw stream inside your request call method just remove the parameter type specification **EndSessionRequest** and insert **Stream**. You're *Web.config* also needs some changes in this case..

```
 <!-- insert into system.web tag -->
 <system.web>
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2000000" />
     <!-- other stuff.. -->
 </system.web>
 <!-- insert into system.serviceModel > bindings -->
 <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
         <webHttpBinding>
             <binding 
                 name="YourBindingName"
                 maxBufferSize="65536"
                 maxreceiveMessageSize="2000000000"
                 transferMode="Streamed" />
         </webHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

And don't forget to set the ***bindingConfiguration="YourBindingName"*** to your service behaviour.

But as *@Ricardo Pontual* already mentioned. It's the third party that's calling your service the wrong way..

Comment: I agree with @Jan Unld, get the raw data stream.  You can then get the raw json string as the argument for counters.  Deserialize with newtonsoft then analyze what you have, an array or dictionary object.  It's a big pain in the butt, but I have done it and can post more code if you like.